# Is there any evidence to support the claim that Richard Burton told John Speke he would return home via Jerusalem after their Nile Quest?

Tags: british-empire, geography, exploration

The book "*[Explorers of the Nile: The Triumph and Tragedy of the Great Victorian Adventure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0300187394)*" by Tim Jeal contradicts with every other books I read regarding the dispute between **Richard Burton and John Speke**, including "*[River of the Gods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385543107)*" by Candice Millard,  "*[A Biography of Sir Richard Francis Burton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140120688)*" by Byron Farwell, "*[Devil Drives A Life of Sir Richard Burton](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393301664)*" by Fawn M. Brodie

The latest book about the dispute between Burton and Speke is ["River of the Gods"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0PQ25mePTk) published in 2022 by [Candice Millard](https://www.candicemillard.com/). Before reading this one I had already read the books by [Byron Farwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byron_Farwell) and [Fawn M. Brodie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fawn_M._Brodie) (both published in 60s). Their versions are similar in that Speke betrayed his leader by going to RGS first announcing he had found the Nile source while Burton was on his way home. By doing this he secured another trip to explore Nile as the leader. And Speke boasted shamelessly several times, "I am sure everybody at Zanzibar knows it that I was the leader and Burton the second of the Expedition."

To quote from "River of the Gods":

> Astonished, Burton wrote that he “found the ground completely cut from under my feet.” As he struggled to understand what had happened to his expedition while he was still in Aden, one thing became painfully clear: Speke was no longer his friend and protégé but his adversary. "My companion now stood forth in his true colours," Burton wrote, "an angry rival."

But Tim Jeal's book provides another version. He came up with a theory that, to quote:

> Burton said "To this [Speke’s map] I would respectfully draw the attention of the committee as there are grave reasons for believing it to be the source of the principal feeder of the White Nile. He compounded the dishonesty of keeping his true beliefs to himself by embarking on a long and increasingly vindictive campaign to discredit Speke."

So Burton told Speke he would return home via Jerusalem.

> By pretending it would be many months before he would return to England, he could have hoped to lull Speke into imagining that he had plenty of time in hand, and need not hurry to the RGS the moment he landed. Then, if Burton caught the very next homeward-bound steamship, and Speke in the meantime had gone to the country to relax with his family, Burton might even arrive first at the RGS and grab command of the next expedition!

To me Tim Jeal's version is hard to believe. When reading his book I find from time to time that his reasoning and logic is flawed. But [New York Times Book Review](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/11/books/review/explorers-of-the-nile-the-triumph-and-tragedy-of-a-great-victorian-adventure-by-tim-jeal-book-review.html) says otherwise, "Explorers of the Nile is a brilliant, scholarly and at times almost unreadably vivid account of the two decades in the middle of the 19th century when the search for the Nile’s source in central Africa was at its height.”

When I research these four authors I find they are all of good renown. So whose version is closer to truth?

BTW, if you are not familiar with Tim Jeal version you may check this article first: [How feud wrecked the reputation of explorer who discovered Nile's source](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2011/sep/11/burton-speke-african-exploration-nile)

Comment: Personally, "a pox on both their houses". There were humans *living* at the so-called "source of the Nile" at the time, and have been nearly as long as there have been humans. Not to mention that the Nile, like all river systems has myriad sources, and its far more geographically correct to talk about its "watershed" or "drainage basin". This was just two British dudes fighting over made-up British dude nonsense.

Comment: @T.E.D. Doesn't this sidestep the question,  though? Although the context of the Scramble for Africa was certainly shameful to say the least, and the whole quest may have been chasing a chimera,  the question appears to be about how the two acted with respect to each other.

Comment: I don't understand why my question was about to close. I don't think it is opinion based because we can draw the conclusion based on the facts. So I provide an answer based on the 4 books I have read (several times)

Comment: I think this question is fine. It's not really "opinion-based" so much as it's "judgment-based," and therefore on-topic.

Comment: @T.E.D. The source of a river is a conventionnal definition and it has consequences over politics of the river, if not in the real flow of concerned river(s). So the question was important. And the fact that humans were living there does not say they KNEW they lived at the Nile source

Comment: @T.E.D. I really do not understand your disdain here. The source of the Nile was a longstanding mystery, even the Romans wrote about it. The explorers were in no way surprised to find people living around the lakes, why would they be? But mapping the route and source of that river was a significant act of courage and endurance that greatly expanded the knowledge of the world.

Comment: I must say I would rather like to see people discuss my question or better give an answer.

Comment: Does Jeal's book have a bibliography? Does he footnote the claim in question?

Comment: Yes, but if you read my answer you can see I just can't trust his words, or use WSJ book review's words "Mr. Jeal makes an almost unanswerable case, but his stridency makes the reader wary."

Comment: I asked the question to ChatGPT and get an answer "there are no recorded statements from Burton or from contemporary accounts that indicate he made such a promise to Speke. However, it is possible that the claim is based on historical speculation or conjecture rather than on documented facts."

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to provide an answer before the question is about to be closed, which I don't understand. I don't think it is opinion based because we can draw the conclusion based on the facts.

I find Tim Jeal's version hard to believe for two reasons,

1. Never had I found elsewhere did Burton believe Speke theory. Only after [Henry Morton Stanley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Morton_Stanley) had proved that almost 20 years later did Burton accept the defeat.
2. Even if we assume that was true for the moment, since he was the leader of their expedition why not just return to RGS asking for another expedition instead of making a lame excuse to Speke that he would return home via Jerusalem?

Tim Jeal's version defended all Speke's actions, tried to portrait Speke as quite a noble and decent man while accused of Burton despicable. Make no mistake, Burton was not a saint either, when talking about their dispute we are truly talking about **the lesser of two evils** here.

But when re-read the story with "River of the Gods" I still can't help to wonder what a jerk Speke was!

His "crimes" according to "River of the Gods" included, but not limited,

1. Betraying Burton
2. Leaving [James Grant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Augustus_Grant) behind on purpose, so he could be the only one who claimed the glory.

> "who had shared in the difficulties, expenses, and dangers of the
> expedition, would be deprived of both the thrill of the moment—seeing
> the Nile as it rushed from the Nyanza—and the glory that was to come."

Tim Jeal's version also wrote "the normally sweet-natured Grant was seized by an uncharacteristic fit of rage".

> In years to come, Speke’s critics would say that he selfishly reserved
> for himself what he confidently believed would turn out to be the
> discovery of the Nile’s source. But Grant would always deny this,
> saying he had been ‘positively unable to walk twenty miles a-day ...
>
> three days after he and Speke had parted company, the normally
> sweet-natured Grant was seized by an uncharacteristic fit of rage. A
> goat-boy, who had briefly lost sight of his flock, was given twenty
> lashes on his orders – a shocking punishment for a minor offence.

3. Accusing [John Petherick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Petherick) taking part in the slave trade and totally ruined Petherick's reputation just because Petherick was late for their meeting.

> "Spreading the rumor that he(Speke) had heard in Gondokoro from
> Petherick’s trading rivals, men whom Petherick had arrested for
> selling enslaved people, Speke suggested that the consul himself had
> taken part in the slave trade. ... For Petherick, the repercussions
> were immediate and devastating."

4. Betraying the then president of RGS, Sir Roderick Murchison, who championed his trip and was fond of him at the beginning of the trip

> giving the full account of his expedition not to the Royal
> Geographical Society (as a tradition ), but to Blackwood. "The idea
> that he would treat the Society and the men who had supported and
> encouraged him with such casual disregard and disrespect astonished
> Murchison... Finally, after months of urging, complaining, and
> demanding, the Royal Geographical Society did receive a short article
> from Speke. The article, however, was so disappointing that Murchison
> dictated a terse letter to the man he had once enthusiastically
> championed, complaining of its “very brief and imperfect character.”

Speke basically betrayed everyone on his second expedition, which makes me hard to believe he was a decent guy.

Accusing innocent John Petherick deserves further discussion because that was a fact everyone agreed but Tim Jeal's once against came up with his own theory.

"Devil drives" said this(in page 221)

> Privately he(Speke) accused Petherick of selling stores which really
> belonged to him. Publicly, with no justification, he accused Petherick
> of participating in the slave trade

But Tim Jeal's explanation was

> Samuel Baker could easily have saved Speke from making this foolish
> allegation by admitting that he himself believed Petherick innocent.
> But Baker wanted to replace Consul Petherick as the man to ‘succour’
> the explorers, and he also hoped to ensure that when Petherick
> eventually arrived, Speke would not feel inclined to let the Welshman
> share in the glory of finding the Luta N’zige. The less Speke liked
> Petherick, the better things would be for Baker – or so Baker appears
> to have calculated.

In Tim Jeal's version [Samuel Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_Baker) was another "evil" guy who tricked innocent/unsophisticated Speke.

Let me give another detail to show why I think Tim Jeal's reasoning and logic was quite flawed.

Before leaving London for his second expedition Speke wrote to Burton a farewell note as a gesture for reconciliation. After he had done so much harm to Burton I think it was quite natural to do that.

"Devil Drives" said (in page 171 ) "it was conventional enough save for the poignantly revealing first line, I cannot leave England addressing you so coldly"

"Rive of the God" added this comment,

> Now, however, as he prepared to take command of his own expedition,
> Speke’s feelings had begun to shift from resentment to magnanimity.
> ... Two days before Speke was to leave on his expedition, he wrote to
> Burton one last time. “My dear Burton,” he wrote, attempting to return
> to a friendlier tone. “I cannot leave England addressing you so coldly...

But Tim Jeal's version said, "Speke’s **true character shines out in a note** he wrote to Burton on 16 April 1860, shortly before leaving England... "

Really, can that gesture be interpreted as "true character shines" ?!

When reading Tim Jeal's book I keep getting the feeling that "the author was quite naive. [This book review at amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0300187394) said my words

> Tim Jeal goes to heroic lengths to establish his hero, Speke, as the
> un-credited one. It is a dramatic tale, and Jeal's sense of injustice
> having been done in this determination, he makes sure you get the
> correct picture; being the author, he has taken on the roles of judge
> and jury, infusing it with new layers of passion. This skews the
> evidence always in favor of Speke and to the detriment of most anyone
> else, particularly Sir Richard Burton.

But again [New York Times Book Review](https://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/11/books/review/explorers-of-the-nile-the-triumph-and-tragedy-of-a-great-victorian-adventure-by-tim-jeal-book-review.html) says otherwise,

> Jeal’s singular achievement is to rescue Speke from his unwarranted
> relegation to the second rank, not only establishing his credentials
> as a pioneering explorer but unearthing at the same time a subtle and
> attractive character who was far from a prude.

[The WJS book review](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424052970203476804576617400543628660) provided a more objective narrative, to quote

> Mr. Jeal is his ardent supporter. Nothing the wily Burton did was, in
> Mr. Jeal's eyes, honest or aboveboard; Speke, by contrast, could do no
> wrong. Mr. Jeal makes an almost unanswerable case, but his stridency
> makes the reader wary.